# Salta de un input a otro sin usar tabindex

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Tengo el siguiente código que me hace saltar de un input a otro a través de un atributo tabindexgt, pero solo salta entre los que tienen ese atributo si hay otro input con otro atributo lo salta. ¿como puedo hacer para saltar de un input a otro sin que tengan el mismo atributo?

Desde ya muchas gracias

```
<Input size="4" tabindexgt="1">
<Input size="4" tabindexdxfiltro="1">
<Input size="4" tabindexgt="2">

$(Window).on('keydown', null, 'Tab', función (event) { 
Event.preventDefault();
Var elemnt, index;
     elemnt = $(event.target);
     If (elemnt.attr('tabindexgt' !== Undefined)) {
          Index == parseInt(elemnt.attr('tabindexgt'));
          If(Index == $('[tabindexgt]:visible').length){
               Index = 0;
          }
          If(!!!$('.ui-autocomplete.ui-widget:visible').length {
              $('[tabindexgt=" ' + (Index + 1).toString() + ' "]'.focus();
          }
     }
 });
```

Comment: La verdad no se entiende bien lo que quieres, pero según lo que leí, te va a "pasar" de un input a otro solo con el mismo atributo, por que esa es la validación que tienes.

Comment: Si esa validación tengo pero necesito validar que si el input tiene otro atributo lo seleccione  así como puse los inputs del primero se va al tercero y ocupo que del primero pase al segundo y después al tercero sin importar el atributo intenté haciéndolo con or(||) pero no me funcionó
Nose si me explique

Comment: lo que quieres es que pase del input #1 al #2, del #2 al #3? sin importar los atributos?. Si es el caso no entiendo para que el script, con la tecla "alt-tab" pasa entre los inputs en el orden que estén en el DOM.

Comment: Mi error, sin importar que tenga distintos atributos,  pero sí que salte del #1 al #2 y del #2 al #3. no soy bueno preguntando

Comment: Reitero: si es solo eso, para que el script? Con solo teclear tab, pasas de un input al otro en el orden que este en el DOM sin necesidad de scrip
ejemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/a0jwn08e/

Comment: Si, se como función la tecla Tab pero no necesito eso ya que dar Tab se va a cualquier cosa incluyendo la URL y todo los botones yo solo lo necesito en los inputs

Comment: En este ejemplo puedes ver como solo salta entre inputs pero no selecciona los que tienen el atributo tabindexdxfiltro jsfiddle.net/yc3q55ag/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si lo que quieres es que la tecla `Tab` vaya recorriendo los inputs (sin importar el atributo `tabindexdxfiltro` o  `tabindexgt` podrías -al principio- asignarle un atributo `data-index` a cada elemento input. Luego al hacer `Tab` sobre un input, pasar al siguiente, o bien al primero si es que hiciste `Tab` en el último.

```js
$(document).find('input').each(function(index) {
  $(this).data('index',index);
});
$(document).on('keydown', 'input',  function (event) {
  $index=$(this).data('index');
  if(event.key==='Tab') {
    event.preventDefault();
    if($index=== $(document).find('input').length-1) {
      $(document).find('input').eq(0).focus();
    } else {
      $(document).find('input').eq($index+1).focus();
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input size="4" tabindexgt="1" >
<input size="4" tabindexdxfiltro="1" >
<input size="4" tabindexgt="2" >

<input size="4" tabindexgt="3" >
<input size="4" tabindexdxfiltro="2" >
<input size="4" tabindexgt="4" >
```

Comment: Muchas gracias eres muy amable